# Retrieving Sub Site data Rest Api is not working for java code

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, java-api

I am trying to get last modified Sub-Sites from sharepoint site using Sharepoint rest api and executing rest calls using Java

I am using below url:

```
https://XXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/XXXX-Test-SharePoint/_api/web/WebInfos?$select=Configuration,Id,Created,Language,LastItemUserModifiedDate,ServerRelativeUrl,WebTemplate,WebTemplateId,LastItemModifiedDate,Title&$filter=LastItemModifiedDate gt datetime'2017-06-05T05:21:56Z' and LastItemModifiedDate le datetime'2017-06-05T10:21:56Z'
```

Request Headers are as below :

```
"Cookie":getCookieValue(sharepointRequest.getCookies())));
"Accept":"application/json";
"Content-Encoding:gzip";
"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)";
"Content-Type":"application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8";
```

But when i execute above url,it is saying Bad Request so I have printed response headers:

```
Header-Key :null            Header-Value[HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
Header-Key :Date            Header-Value[Mon, 05 Jun 2017 10:22:08 GMT]
Header-Key :Content-Length  Header-Value[311]
Header-Key :Connection      Header-Value[close]
Header-Key :Content-Type    Header-Value[text/html; charset=us-ascii]
Header-Key :Server          Header-Value[Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0]
```

Now when i execute same URL with REST postman through browser 
it is giving me proper result and response header by REST postman client is as below :

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
X-SP-SERVERSTATE: ReadOnly=0
request-id: bf9df89d-e012-3000-bc42-3178c4635d41
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.6525
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
SPRequestDuration: 71
Last-Modified: Mon, 05 Jun 2017 09:56:22 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
SPRequestGuid: bf9df89d-e012-3000-bc42-3178c4635d41
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Mon, 05 Jun 2017 09:56:23 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type :application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
SPClientServiceRequestDuration: 34
DATASERVICEVERSION: 3.0
Expires: Sun, 21 May 2017 09:56:22 GMT
```

I am not able to figure out what is happening